# Attempt to present UIAlertController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9, hierarchy

I'm trying to check the UIAlertController in iOS 9 for my sample application and while run it then I had found warning in console. I'm using Xcode 7 and Objective C.

Please find the below warning message in console.

> Warning: Attempt to present < UIAlertController: 0x7fb1bb5be040 > on
>   < ViewController: 0x7fb1bb5aef30 > whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

Please find the below code for more information.

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                               message:@"This is an alert."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: where are you calling this code ?

Comment: Are you calling this on viewDidload?

Comment: @Mr.T : Yes I am calling in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess, you are trying to present the alert on view did load. You get the error:

> Warning: Attempt to present < UIAlertController: 0x7fb1bb5be040 > on <
>   ViewController: 0x7fb1bb5aef30 > whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

because, in view did load the views are not yet available to display to the user. Hence you can't present the alert. Move the code into `viewDidAppear`

Comment: This should get more upvotes. The commonly accepted solution of using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {...});` is a hack.