# Warning - Attempt to present UIAlertController null in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an UIAlertController running in my project which is connected through UIButton.My code works ok.But,Everytime when I pressed the button Xcode console printing an alert as below and I went through all the similar question been asked in stackOverflow but no answer.[Attempt to present UIAlertController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016497/attempt-to-present-uialertcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-th)

```
2016-10-03 19:14:35.854 xxxxxx[85186:7214348] Warning: Attempt to present<UIAlertController: 0x7f8d99450820>  on <yyyyyyy.ViewController: 0x7f8d9a025200> which is already presenting (null)
```

My Code Below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.moreButton.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width / 2, y: view.frame.height / 2, width: 100, height: 40)

    moreButton.center = view.center
    moreButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkText.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    moreButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    moreButton.setTitle("More", for: UIControlState())
    moreButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
    moreButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    moreButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    moreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.moreButtonAction(_:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

    self.view.addSubview(self.moreButton)
    }


    func moreButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    myAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

    let myAction_1 = UIAlertAction(title: " Title 1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    })

    let myAction_2 = UIAlertAction(title: " Title 2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    })

    let myAction_3 = UIAlertAction(title: " Title 3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    })

    let myAction_4 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    })

    myAlert.addAction(myAction_1)
    myAlert.addAction(myAction_2)
    myAlert.addAction(myAction_3)
    myAlert.addAction(myAction_4)

    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: show us the code presenting the alert controller.

Comment: @ozgur i just uploaded my code....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are trying to present an `alertController` that is already **active**. You could check if your controller has an active alert otherwise show it. This will remove the warning. So basically move your `self.present row` with the following:

```
if !(self.navigationController?.visibleViewController?.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self))! {
   self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Replace your `moreActionButton` function with the following:

```
func moreButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    myAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

    let myAction_1 = UIAlertAction(title: " Title 1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    })

    let myAction_2 = UIAlertAction(title: " Title 2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    })

    let myAction_3 = UIAlertAction(title: " Title 3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("3")

    })

    let myAction_4 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    })

    myAlert.addAction(myAction_1)
    myAlert.addAction(myAction_2)
    myAlert.addAction(myAction_3)
    myAlert.addAction(myAction_4)

    if !(self.navigationController?.visibleViewController?.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self))! {
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i put this code. i tried inside  my alertView but i am getting  a crash...thanks

Comment: @Joe, check the update. So simply replace your moreActionButton function with the one I added in the answer.

Comment: .Thanks mate your code works..appreciate your effort thanks again.