# Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x...> on <UITabBarController: 0x...> whose view is not in the window Hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'll try to keep this simple. I had Three View Controllers. On the third screen, I load a WebView that allows people to upload images from their photo Library. The problem is when they try to click on **Photo Library** or **Camera** it goes back to the ***initial Viewcontroller*** and gives me this warning.

> Warning: Attempt to present `<UIImagePickerController: 0x...>` on `<UITabBarController: 0x...>` whose view does not appear in the hierarchy!

[Example photo to choose from Photo Library or Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjZbA.png)

Here is my Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadAddressURL()
}  


func loadAddressURL() {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://ollieandfinch.com/tenantschoiceupload")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: requestURL as! URL)
    uploadPage.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}
```

Comment: do not use viewDidLoad to present. Use viewWillAppear/ViewDidAppear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to present UIAlertController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016497/attempt-to-present-uialertcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-th)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The error in your post is incomplete and the code you posted looks irrelevant, please post the code specifically relating to the presentation of the view controller.